# Find matching Pandas dataframe rows with subset of column values within tolerance

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a CSV file from a time-ordered data capture that represents data values flowing into a system interleaved with data values flowing out. The output is downsampled, and some values suffer a slight degradation in resolution, whereas others undergo unit conversion. But one should be able to unambiguously match an output row with the input row that preceded. I'm looking for a way to do it without dropping to for loops.

Here's a toy dataset with random numbers. Columns A-E are the input values and Columns F-I are the outputs:

|  | A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H | I |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 142 | 268.4620314 | 0.88795354 | -36.14294272 | 24.83502189 | -5.888309718 |  |  |  |  |
| 143 | 260.5989964 | 0.575051317 | 22.72606608 | -6.997301513 | 26.98494968 |  |  |  |  |
| 144 |  |  |  |  |  | -5.344932556 | 1.699924469 | 183.7252502 | TRUE |
| 145 | 238.5640776 | 0.56440478 | -25.11744339 | 28.06150565 | 15.57436172 |  |  |  |  |
| 146 | 146.5759824 | 0.511427295 | -34.70449463 | -4.724835838 | -3.086899544 |  |  |  |  |
| 147 | 81.38048808 | 0.818582364 | -30.30649328 | 12.9429191 | 18.07471308 |  |  |  |  |
| 148 | 101.7955178 | 0.964528989 | 34.94924089 | -34.15163516 | 5.503329208 |  |  |  |  |
| 149 | 124.8002222 | 0.834127362 | 8.467252179 | 34.6700403 | -5.337944916 |  |  |  |  |
| 150 |  |  |  |  |  | 22.72605133 | -6.99729538 | 260.5988159 | TRUE |
| 151 | 144.1608728 | 0.598091181 | 36.13362969 | 10.90960903 | -18.82224584 |  |  |  |  |
| 152 | 119.9718214 | 1.003923003 | -32.6886618 | -29.58910529 | -11.96037248 |  |  |  |  |

Column I indicates that the row is an output row. Note that row 150 has numbers that match row 143. F:150 matches C:143, G:150 matches D:143, and H:150 matches A:143. What column pairs should match is fixed and known; i.e., column pairs F/C, G/D, and H/A will always match.

There are more columns than shown, this is reduced to demonstrate the concept. Fortunately, if I must drop to for loops, the dataset is only a few thousand rows.

The puzzle is to find the matching input row that precedes each output row, which could be any number of rows prior.

I tried finding the answer to this question on stackoverflow and elsewhere and came close, but I think my case has enough wrinkles to perhaps warrant its own entry. None of the pages I found quite match my use case, because

1. All of the rows are in one dataframe
2. None of the rows in the dataframe match across all columns,
3. And the value matching involves applying tolerances and/or unit conversions.

I can avoid the columns that require unit conversions; one thing I must do is verify the conversions are done correctly, so can't really rely on those columns to match rows. For comparison with a tolerance, one page had the hint of using np.isclose. I thought maybe I should split the dataframe so the outputs and inputs are separated, but all the solutions I found seemed to suggest that joining the two is part of the solution; perhaps there is a particular way they should be joined, I just don't know how.

But it seems, given the other things I have to do once the input and output rows are matched, it would be most efficient to have a new dataframe with the output values concatenated on the matching input row (leaving the other rows intact).

Comment: Should the matches always be on the same columns (F->C ; G->D ; H->A)? Can you provide the explicit expected output?

Comment: Yes, as I said, the column pairs that should match are fixed (always the same) and known a priori. The expected output would be a dataframe where the matched input row has the matching output row concatenated on the end

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like it could be a `.merge_asof` problem.

That can be used to find "near" matches - which can then be filtered to find the match with the minimum distance.

```
# split up into inputs/outputs
inputs  = df.loc[ df["I"].isna(), slice("A", "E")].reset_index()
outputs = df.loc[~df["I"].isna(), slice("F", "H")].reset_index()

mapping = [("A", "H"), ("C", "F"), ("D", "G")]

# Find near matches for each criteria
# drop_duplicates as rows could match on more than 1
near = pd.concat(
   [
      pd.merge_asof(
         inputs.sort_values(left),
         outputs.sort_values(right),
         left_on=left, 
         right_on=right, 
         direction="nearest",
         # tolerance=0.001,
      )
      for left, right in mapping
   ], 
   ignore_index=True
).drop_duplicates(subset=["index_x", "index_y"])

# Keep only matches where input comes before output
near = near.loc[near["index_x"] < near["index_y"]]

# Calculate distance for each column pair and total distance
for left, right in mapping:
   near[f"{left}/{right}"] = (near[left] - near[right]).abs()
   
near["distance"] = (
   near[[f"{left}/{right}" for left, right in mapping]].sum(axis=1)
)
```

```
    index_x           A         B          C          D          E  index_y          F         G           H     I         A/H        C/F        D/G    distance
6       145  238.564078  0.564405 -25.117443  28.061506  15.574362      150  22.726051 -6.997295  260.598816  True   22.034738  47.843495  35.058801  104.937034
7       143  260.598996  0.575051  22.726066  -6.997302  26.984950      150  22.726051 -6.997295  260.598816  True    0.000180   0.000015   0.000006    0.000201
8       142  268.462031  0.887954 -36.142943  24.835022  -5.888310      150  22.726051 -6.997295  260.598816  True    7.863216  58.868994  31.832317   98.564527
9       142  268.462031  0.887954 -36.142943  24.835022  -5.888310      144  -5.344933  1.699924  183.725250  True   84.736781  30.798010  23.135097  138.669889
16      148  101.795518  0.964529  34.949241 -34.151635   5.503329      150  22.726051 -6.997295  260.598816  True  158.803298  12.223190  27.154340  198.180827
21      146  146.575982  0.511427 -34.704495  -4.724836  -3.086900      150  22.726051 -6.997295  260.598816  True  114.022833  57.430546   2.272460  173.725839
```

For each output find the row with the minimum distance:

```
>>> near.loc[near.groupby("index_y")["distance"].idxmin()]
   index_x           A         B          C          D         E  index_y          F         G           H     I        A/H        C/F        D/G    distance
9      142  268.462031  0.887954 -36.142943  24.835022  -5.88831      144  -5.344933  1.699924  183.725250  True  84.736781  30.798010  23.135097  138.669889
7      143  260.598996  0.575051  22.726066  -6.997302  26.98495      150  22.726051 -6.997295  260.598816  True   0.000180   0.000015   0.000006    0.000201
```

In this case `142` is matched to `144` and `143` is matched to `150`.

`tolerance` can be used to limit the range of what is considered a match.

```
pd.merge_asof(
   inputs.sort_values("C"),
   outputs.sort_values("F"),
   left_on="C", 
   right_on="F", 
   direction="nearest",
   tolerance=0.001
)
```

```
   index_x           A         B          C          D          E  index_y          F         G           H     I
0      142  268.462031  0.887954 -36.142943  24.835022  -5.888310      NaN        NaN       NaN         NaN   NaN
1      146  146.575982  0.511427 -34.704495  -4.724836  -3.086900      NaN        NaN       NaN         NaN   NaN
2      152  119.971821  1.003923 -32.688662 -29.589105 -11.960372      NaN        NaN       NaN         NaN   NaN
3      147   81.380488  0.818582 -30.306493  12.942919  18.074713      NaN        NaN       NaN         NaN   NaN
4      145  238.564078  0.564405 -25.117443  28.061506  15.574362      NaN        NaN       NaN         NaN   NaN
5      149  124.800222  0.834127   8.467252  34.670040  -5.337945      NaN        NaN       NaN         NaN   NaN
6      143  260.598996  0.575051  22.726066  -6.997302  26.984950    150.0  22.726051 -6.997295  260.598816  True
7      148  101.795518  0.964529  34.949241 -34.151635   5.503329      NaN        NaN       NaN         NaN   NaN
8      151  144.160873  0.598091  36.133630  10.909609 -18.822246      NaN        NaN       NaN         NaN   NaN
```

Comment: This is nice (I love `merge_asof` myself) but two important points: 1- this doesn't restrict the matches to the previous rows, 2- this assumes F is always matching in C and ignores what happens in G/H.

Comment: @mozway Ah - I had just chosen C/F as a quick example and (wrongly) thought it could be extended. I did not realize you can only match against a "single column" with `.merge_asof`. I suppose you would need multiple calls in that case? Thank you for the corrections.

Comment: @mozway, But the first part of the solution works, across all matching columns and restricts to inputs before the outputs, doesn't it? It's just the example with tolerance added that does not?

Comment: @jqurious, where did "inputs" and "outputs" come from? I take it they came from the original dataframe? how did you split it?

Comment: @Phil If you check the revision history of my answer I didn't have `near["index_x"] < near["index_y"]` in the original example. It also appears I removed inputs/outputs by mistake during my last edit. Fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

##### new answer: matching with fixed column mappings

```
mapper = {'F': 'C', 'G': 'D', 'H': 'A'}
cols = list(mapper)

# extract left part and convert to numpy array
out = df[mapper.values()].copy()
a1 = out.to_numpy()

# extract columns of right part and convert to array
a2 = df[cols].to_numpy()

# find indices of the complete matches of the broadcasted comparison
# here we define a tolerance with the difference
x, y = np.nonzero(np.tril(np.isclose(a1, a2[:, None], atol=0.0001)
                            .all(axis=-1)
                          )
              )

# this part is optional
# this is to deduplicate in case there can be more than one match
# this keeps the latest match
idx = len(x)-np.unique(x[::-1], return_index=True)[1]-1
x = x[idx]
y = y[idx]

# assign the matched rows
out.loc[out.index[y], cols] = a2[x]
```

Output:

```
             C          D           A          F         G           H
142 -36.142943  24.835022  268.462031        NaN       NaN         NaN
143  22.726066  -6.997302  260.598996  22.726051 -6.997295  260.598816
144        NaN        NaN         NaN        NaN       NaN         NaN
145 -25.117443  28.061506  238.564078        NaN       NaN         NaN
146 -34.704495  -4.724836  146.575982        NaN       NaN         NaN
147 -30.306493  12.942919   81.380488        NaN       NaN         NaN
148  34.949241 -34.151635  101.795518        NaN       NaN         NaN
149   8.467252  34.670040  124.800222        NaN       NaN         NaN
150        NaN        NaN         NaN        NaN       NaN         NaN
151  36.133630  10.909609  144.160873        NaN       NaN         NaN
152 -32.688662 -29.589105  119.971821        NaN       NaN         NaN
```

##### older answer: matching any cell independently of the columns

If you have a reasonable number of rows, one option would be to perform numpy broadcasting, comparing all non-NA cells of the left part with all of the right part and finding combinations that match on all columns of the right part:

```
cols1 = slice('A', 'E')
cols2 = slice('F', 'H')

# extract left part without NaN and convert to numpy array
out = df.loc[:, cols1].dropna(how='all')
a1 = out.to_numpy()

# extract columns of right part and convert to array
cols = df.loc[:, cols2].columns
a2 = df.loc[:, cols].dropna(how='all').to_numpy()

# find indices of the complete matches of the broadcasted comparison
# here we define a tolerance with the difference
x, y = np.nonzero(np.isclose(a1, a2[..., None, None], atol=0.0001)
                    .any(axis=-1).all(axis=1)
                  )

# this part is optional
# this is to deduplicate in case there can be more than one match
# this keeps the latest match
idx = len(x)-np.unique(x[::-1], return_index=True)[1]-1
x = x[idx]
y = y[idx]

# assign the matched rows
out.loc[out.index[y], cols] = a2[x]
```

Output:

```
              A         B          C          D          E          F         G           H
142  268.462031  0.887954 -36.142943  24.835022  -5.888310        NaN       NaN         NaN
143  260.598996  0.575051  22.726066  -6.997302  26.984950  22.726051 -6.997295  260.598816
145  238.564078  0.564405 -25.117443  28.061506  15.574362        NaN       NaN         NaN
146  146.575982  0.511427 -34.704495  -4.724836  -3.086900        NaN       NaN         NaN
147   81.380488  0.818582 -30.306493  12.942919  18.074713        NaN       NaN         NaN
148  101.795518  0.964529  34.949241 -34.151635   5.503329        NaN       NaN         NaN
149  124.800222  0.834127   8.467252  34.670040  -5.337945        NaN       NaN         NaN
151  144.160873  0.598091  36.133630  10.909609 -18.822246        NaN       NaN         NaN
152  119.971821  1.003923 -32.688662 -29.589105 -11.960372        NaN       NaN         NaN
```

Example on a different input with duplicates and matches for all rows of the right part:

```
                A         B          C          D          E          F         G           H
141.0  183.725250  0.987654  -5.344932   1.699925   1.234568  -5.344933  1.699924  183.725250
142.0  268.462031  0.887954 -36.142943  24.835022  -5.888310        NaN       NaN         NaN
143.0  260.598996  0.575051  22.726066  -6.997302  26.984950        NaN       NaN         NaN
143.5  260.598996  0.575051  22.726066  -6.997302  26.984950  22.726051 -6.997295  260.598816
145.0  238.564078  0.564405 -25.117443  28.061506  15.574362        NaN       NaN         NaN
146.0  146.575982  0.511427 -34.704495  -4.724836  -3.086900        NaN       NaN         NaN
147.0   81.380488  0.818582 -30.306493  12.942919  18.074713        NaN       NaN         NaN
148.0  101.795518  0.964529  34.949241 -34.151635   5.503329        NaN       NaN         NaN
149.0  124.800222  0.834127   8.467252  34.670040  -5.337945        NaN       NaN         NaN
151.0  144.160873  0.598091  36.133630  10.909609 -18.822246        NaN       NaN         NaN
152.0  119.971821  1.003923 -32.688662 -29.589105 -11.960372        NaN       NaN         NaN
153.0  184.725250  0.987654  -5.344932   1.699925   1.234568        NaN       NaN         NaN
```

If you want to restrict to the previous values, you need to compare with the original full shape and `np.tril`, you can drop the NaN later:

```
cols1 = slice('A', 'E')
cols2 = slice('F', 'H')

out = df.loc[:, cols1]
a1 = out.to_numpy()

cols = df.loc[:, cols2].columns
a2 = df.loc[:, cols].to_numpy()

x, y = np.nonzero(np.tril(np.isclose(a1, a2[..., None, None],
                                     atol=0.0001)
                            .any(axis=-1).all(axis=1)
                         ))

idx = len(x)-np.unique(x[::-1], return_index=True)[1]-1
x = x[idx]
y = y[idx]

out.loc[out.index[y], cols] = a2[x]
```

Output:

```
                A         B          C          D          E          F         G           H
141.0  183.725250  0.987654  -5.344932   1.699925   1.234568  -5.344933  1.699924  183.725250
142.0  268.462031  0.887954 -36.142943  24.835022  -5.888310        NaN       NaN         NaN
143.0  260.598996  0.575051  22.726066  -6.997302  26.984950        NaN       NaN         NaN
143.5  260.598996  0.575051  22.726066  -6.997302  26.984950  22.726051 -6.997295  260.598816
144.0         NaN       NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN       NaN         NaN
145.0  238.564078  0.564405 -25.117443  28.061506  15.574362        NaN       NaN         NaN
146.0  146.575982  0.511427 -34.704495  -4.724836  -3.086900        NaN       NaN         NaN
147.0   81.380488  0.818582 -30.306493  12.942919  18.074713        NaN       NaN         NaN
148.0  101.795518  0.964529  34.949241 -34.151635   5.503329        NaN       NaN         NaN
149.0  124.800222  0.834127   8.467252  34.670040  -5.337945        NaN       NaN         NaN
150.0         NaN       NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN       NaN         NaN
151.0  144.160873  0.598091  36.133630  10.909609 -18.822246        NaN       NaN         NaN
152.0  119.971821  1.003923 -32.688662 -29.589105 -11.960372        NaN       NaN         NaN
153.0  184.725250  0.987654  -5.344932   1.699925   1.234568        NaN       NaN         NaN
```

Comment: Wow, I totally did not expect a solution that dropped out of pandas and back in again. Some questions: 1) A reasonable number of rows would be...? 2) Do I understand correctly that this solution is general enough to find matches between any two columns, and not necessarily the same columns for each output row? Would there be any efficiency gained by adopting the assumption that the column relationships are fixed?

Comment: Yes this solution find matches between cells within a row independently of the columns. Thus it computes all combinations, which is memory expensive. It could definitely be improved using the assumption that columns pairs are always the same.

Comment: I'll update later, I'm on my phone AFK at the moment, which is not so practical to rework the answer ;)

Comment: It should work by slicing in the correct order, changing the `a2[..., None, None]` to `a2[..., None]` and removing `any(axis=-1)`, but I can't load the data to check ATM, let's see in a few hours ;)

Comment: @Phil I finally had a moment to update the answer with a fixed mapping!

Comment: Thanks! I'll look it over, looks great. Do you have a ballpark on efficiency improvement compared to the old answer? Just curious.

Comment: The previous method was `O(n^2*m^2)` with `n`/`m` the number of rows/cols. This one is "only" `O(n^2)`. Give it a try on the real data and let me know ;)

Comment: so I'm generally new to some of the finer points of np arrays and manipulation. I had to look up broadcasting. I get how it applies to arithmetic operations with numpy arrays. It was less obvious to me that calling a function like np.isclose() with differently shaped arrays would cause broadcasting rules to also apply. Would this be true of *any* numpy function that receives arrays as arguments? I could find no examples anywhere else, all the documentation on line had the most simple examples where the two arrays are shaped the same.

Comment: I'm picking apart the solution now to understand it better. I'm also unclear on the use of np.tril, I presume because of the small size of the toy dataset the operation appears to be trivial; i.e., input and output are identical. isclose.all(axis=-1) does not appear to have produced a 2D array symmetric across the diagonal...is it perhaps not needed with the restriction on the column matches?

Comment: :/ The other thing I have to do is concatenate *all* of the output values to the end of the matching row from inputs with *all* of the values there, not just the matching ones. Not sure how to do that. If you don't have any more time to give, I can try to play with it...

Comment: @Phil `tril` is to mask the lower triangle of the broadcasted array, this is to ensure that we only match **prior** values, if you remove it this will match the latest rows even if after the query. For the second question, just `join` back the accessory columns to the output ;)

Comment: Why doesn't this work?
theslice = slice("F","I");
df.loc[df.index[y], theslice] = df.loc[df.index[x], theslice]